# Problem with Confluent.Kafka.ConsumeException: Broker: Message size too large

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I deployed a test Kafka locally in my docker. Uploaded messages for 30kb, but consumers cannot receive messages if I connect like a new group.
`ConsumerConfig: AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest`
All broker settings and themes are default

Comment: Please share your code and how you write to kafka, writing to kafka must be using the kafka protocol, and not http protocol

Comment: "Message size too large" seems self explanatory, so how do you know messages are actually 30Kb? Are you sending more than one of those messages at a time?